# Google App Engine Slow Logs Updates

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

This issue is bothering me for a long time -

I'm using Google App Engine \ Java

The logs take forever to update : If for example I test my app and a server error occurs at 12:34 , I will only see the appropriate error log 'some time' later , when some time is usually an hour at a minimum . Refreshing the admin console or whatever doesn't help . This makes it hell for me to debug my app (debugging locally of course isn't helpful since it's cloud related bugs) .

Anyone else had this experience ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be experiencing [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5494) - there is a potential solution also attached the bug report, which may alleviate your issue.